# Replacing text in cmd using a substring

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd

I need to open a file and search for substring. Then replace the other text on the same line.

Have to search for text: `#define MyAppVersion` and replace the version inside the double quotes (this is dynamic, will be fetched from a different file).

```
#define MyAppVersion "1.0.0"
```

So here is what I currently have:

```
rem version num to be retrieved elsewhere, set here for simplicity on sample
set VER=1.1.0
powershell -Command "(gc sample.iss) -replace '#define MyAppVersion', '#define MyAppVersion "%VER%"' | Out-File sample.iss"
```

But this only outputs like this:

```
#define MyAppVersion 1.1.0 "1.0.0"
```

How can I change the entire line then without using any 3rd party plugins?

Thanks!

Comment: Well, the output exactly corresponds with what you told the command to do; I could imagine there is some regular-expression support...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got it to work,

```
set VER=1.1.0
powershell -Command "(gc sample.iss) -replace '#define MyAppVersion.+', '#define MyAppVersion "\"%VER%"\"' | Out-File mod.iss"
```

The `.+` will match the rest of this line